# Google Analytics in a PWA Progressive Web App

Tags: google-analytics, progressive-web-apps

I have been reading various tutorials on Google Analytics within a PWA and they tend to centre on recording events vs page views. I am using a fairly standard boiler plate service worker with a CacheFirstSafe policy (i.e. if network available use it, otherwise try cache).  I am initially trying to ensure that page views are recorded when the app is online so have added the following fairly basic regex for all GET requests:

```
    // For HTML requests, try the network first, fall back to the cache, finally the offline page
    if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') !== -1 || request.url.match(/^https:\/\/www\.google\-analytics\.com\/*/)) {
```

It works ok and lets google analytic traffic through whilst online.  The other option is to move the regex to the non-GET condition:

```
    // Always fetch non-GET requests from the network
    if (request.method !== 'GET' || request.url.match(/\/browserLink/ig) || request.url.match(/^https:\/\/www\.google\-analytics\.com\/*/)) {
```

I want to know if this is a valid approach. it seems too simple?